# What am I misunderstanding about this fluid dynamics calculation?

Tags: javascript, math, simulation, fluid

The last question was deleted for being too short and vague, so this time I will try to be as verbose as possible.

I am using Javascript to implement a basic physically accurate SPH following [this paper](https://cg.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/publications/2014_EG_SPH_STAR.pdf). All I want in the beginning is to get the basics working, just to get through the first algorithm.

I start with a test case of just two particles at (0.05, 0.05) and (0.06999, 0.05). Their sample radii just touch, and I am already getting weird numbers.

[image]

This is how I calculate the densities and pressures:

```
for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++)
{
    var pi = particles[i];

    pi.density = 0;

    for (var j = 0; j < pi.neighbors.length; j++)
    {
        var n  = pi.neighbors[j];
        var pj = n.p;

        var h  = (pi.sampleDist + pj.sampleDist) / 2;

        n.r    = subv(pi.pos, pj.pos); // subv() subtracts first vector from second
        n.dist = length(n.r);
        n.q    = n.dist/h;

        pi.density += pj.mass * W(n.q, h, 2);
    }

    pi.pressure = pi.stiffness * (Math.pow(pi.density / pi.restDensity, 7) - 1);
}
```

using the smoothing kernel

```
function W(q, h, d)
{
    var f = 0;

         if (0 <= q && q < 1) f = 2/3 - sqr(q) + 1/2*cube(q); // 2/3 - q² + 1/2q³
    else if (1 <= q && q < 2) f = 1/6 * cube(2 - q);          // 1/6(2-q)³

    return 3/Tau / Math.pow(h, d) * f;
}
```

These are the settings I'm using:

mass: **0.001 kg**
h: **0.01 m**
rest density: **1000 kg/m³**
stiffness: **0.2**

In the case of just two particles with these settings, each particle's density becomes

`pi.density = pj.mass * W(n.q, h, 2);` = 0.001 * W(1.99899, 0.01, 2) = 0.001 * 0.00000079577 = 0.00000000079...

This number makes sense to me — there is almost nothing around, so the density is almost zero.

But now I go to calculate the pressure force, which I do like this:

[image]

Here is my implementation:

```
var Fp = {x:0, y:0};

if (pi.density !== 0)
{
    var Vp = valueGradient(pi, 'pressure');

    Fp.x = -pi.mass/pi.density * Vp.x;
    Fp.y = -pi.mass/pi.density * Vp.y;
}
```

[image]

```
function valueGradient(pi, A) // A is a scalar
{
    var vA = {x: 0, y: 0};

    for (var j = 0; j < pi.neighbors.length; j++)
    {
        var n  = pi.neighbors[j];
        var pj = n.p;
        var h  = (pi.sampleDist + pj.sampleDist) / 2;

        var f = pj.mass / pj.density * pj[A];

        var vw = VW(n, h);

        vA.x += f * vw.x;
        vA.y += f * vw.y;
    }

    return vA;
}
```

[image]

```
function VW(n, h)
{
    var dw = 
          dW(n.q, h, 2)
        / (n.dist * h);

    return {
        x: dw * n.r.x,
        y: dw * n.r.y };
}


function dW(q, h, d) // derivative of kernel
{
    var f = 0;

         if (0 <= q && q < 1) f = -2*q + 3/2*sqr(q); // -2q + 3/2q²
    else if (1 <= q && q < 2) f = -1/2 * sqr(2 - q); // -1/2(2-q)²

    return 3/Tau / Math.pow(h, d) * f;
}
```

But something is going wrong, because when the particles sample radii just touch, the repulsive force is enormous, and when they're close it goes to zero. I get why this would be happening, because given my settings there are lots of 0.000... everywhere, and with the density so tiny, dividing by all these 0.000... will give huge numbers in the end. So it makes sense why those numbers are there, and so I suspect that I'm misunderstanding something fundamental.

[image]

This feels... backwards. What mistake am I making? I keep looking at the kernel derivative...

Another thing is that the forces are not strictly symmetrical as they should be, they tend to stay diagonal until the difference in one of the coordinates is around zero, where they suddenly flip.

[image]

I feel like I'm messing up the differential equations somewhere...

A live version of this code that can be stepped through is at [www.bourt.com/particles](http://www.bourt.com/particles). The code in question is in [simulation.js](http://www.bourt.com/particles/simulation.js), [physics.js](http://www.bourt.com/particles/physics.js) and [kernel.js](http://www.bourt.com/particles/kernel.js).

Comment: What's that `sqr` function doing? Why not just use `Math.pow` ?

Comment: Dunno, just a little more compact and easier to read I guess...